# How do I call a function upon the loading of individual elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to increment a number variable upon the creation of a dynamically added table (this number would be added to the name of the table. example: table_dynamicID). However, the table will never be clicked so as to add an onclick function to it. The 'this' keyword needs to be passed into the function that the event calls so that I can determine this table's id when it is created... So what event can I pass to an HTML table that will be called automatically when it is created?

I'm sorry, guys. It's 4am. I need to go to sleep. I'll explain everything in the daytime sometime. Please hang tight and help me further when I post a screen shot and further explanation. I'll try to do this later today after work sometime..

James

Comment: Which reason to do this work? Why you need to assing ID's to all tables?

Comment: I need to have assign dynamic names (a common name, underscore with a number variable that increments with each newly added element) so that I can validate each element and add them to the database. If they didn't have that number at the end of each name, what I do to one element (such as an input box) would affect them all. However, since I don't know in advance what each element's unique name would be, I need to check the name at the time I wish to perform a unique validation, as well as other manipulation to the element before submitting the form into the database..

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event that will call you when that particular tag is loaded.  You can hook when the page is loaded and then run javascript to find the table in the DOM by id or class or tag and then operate on it.

Comment: I appreciate the response. But I need to get the element's name 'without' foreknowing it. Any suggestions on how I can get the table's name passed to a different function, not tied to the table?? I'm already calling a function when a dropdownlist is selected. How can I get this table's name upon the execution of the onchange of a select dropdownbox?

Comment: Show us the HTML and we can give you ideas how to get the table.  If the table is the ONLY table in the page, it can be fetched by tag name.  Otherwise, there has to be a unique set of characteristics about it (id, classes, parent objects, tag names, attributes, etc...) that allows one to create some unique CSS selector that will target the object.  We can only answer that question if you show us the HTML of the table and the surrounding (e.g. containing) objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are ready to use jQuery, you can do this using the optional [eventData] parameter of bind or similar functions:

```
var tbl_name = new String();
dyn_table();

$('#select').bind('change keyup', {element:tbl_name}, function(){
  window.alert('Table name: ' + event.data.element);
});

function dyn_table(){
  // create the table and make it's name known everywhere
  tbl_name = 'XYZ';
}
```

Each time the value in `#select` changes, the current value of  `tbl_name` is displayed

Comment: Sorry. I've been busy these last few days. I'm going to post my HTML and Javascript and attempt to explain, again, what I'm doing and need to do. I will look at your code in the daytime so I can see if it solves my issue. Please consider my code I'm posting too, though. Thanks, Nabil..